# Which is grammatically correct between these two?

Tags: grammar

CONTEXT:

I love the way you "see" <strike>the</strike> life.
         Or
I love the way you "look" at life.

Can I replace see with look as in definitions, look means to see with effort and here the person is seeing with effort.
I don't know if I am correct but I need justification for this.

Here is a link: http://www.azquotes.com/quote/1197543
In these types of sentences which indicated to see with effort or makes a sense of seeing with effort, can I use look.

Comment: *The [way I see things,*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way+I+see+things%2Cway+I+look+at+things&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cway%20I%20see%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20I%20look%20at%20things%3B%2Cc0) there's nothing to choose between ***seeing*** and ***looking at*** in most contexts. Your linked example strikes me as largely meaningless playing with words anyway, but *in that specific context* it would be very strange indeed to say *The way you **look at** me is the way I am*.

Comment: I'd say what she actually means is *The picture captures the essence of how I'd like you to see me* (because I look innocent and pure in this carefully-staged photoshoot). So there's "effort" there on the part of the sitter and photographer, but as a general principle I don't think either of these usages have any implications as regards "effort" on the part of the addressee / viewer,

Comment: +1 ... +1 @FumbleFingers If you are going to persist in typing faster than I can, I may as well go back to my chess game.

Answer (score 3):

"Look" is not about effort, it is about intention. "The way you look at life" implies that you have made a choice about how you see it.